# Radius Search on OpenGeoDb

Tags: mysql

I am working to create a database that contains all possible geographical coordinates and postal codes for locations inside Germany. I am making use of the OpenGeoDb project. I have setup the database, and now I am trying to incorporate Radius search in it. The instructions for executing a radius search are available in the [(German Language) OpenGeoDb wiki](http://opengeodb.giswiki.org/wiki/OpenGeoDB_-_Umkreissuche). I am trying to execute the given query but it gives me an error.

First I create a table in which the required data from the database is imported to:

```
CREATE TABLE `zip_coordinates` (
zc_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  zc_loc_id INT NOT NULL ,
    zc_zip VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
    zc_location_name VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
    zc_lat DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
    zc_lon DOUBLE NOT NULL
)
```

Then to import the data to the table zip_coordinate I use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO zip_coordinates (zc_loc_id, zc_zip, zc_location_name, zc_lat, zc_lon)
SELECT gl.loc_id, plz.text_val, name.text_val, coord.lat, coord.lon
FROM geodb_textdata plz
LEFT JOIN geodb_textdata name ON name.loc_id = plz.loc_id
LEFT JOIN geodb_locations gl ON gl.loc_id = plz.loc_id
LEFT JOIN geodb_hierarchies as tier ON plz.loc_id = tier.loc_id 
LEFT JOIN geodb_coordinates coord ON plz.loc_id = coord.loc_id
WHERE plz.text_type =500300000
  AND name.text_type =500100000
  AND tier.id_lvl1 = 104
  AND tier.id_lvl2 = 105 
  AND name.text_locale = "de" 
  AND (
        gl.loc_type =100600000
        OR 
        gl.loc_type =100700000
);
```

I get an error when I try to execute the above mentioned query that `zc_lat` can not be `NULL`.
I still haven't figured out a way to get around this problem. Your help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and fix the formatting?  If you are going to ask questions here, knowing how to format code is important.  It isn't that hard, if you try.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem yesterday...
It worked for me when i removed the conditions wich include   "tier"
cause this refers to a table wich is empty....